# What grammatical function does 見よがし have?

Tags: words

When I looked it up in my 3 go to resources, Jisho, Weblio and Eijirou, the first two completely struck out, and Eijirou only shows it as part of これ見よがし. Just how does one use this term?

Comment: It's a word compound that translates to "look-at-this-definitely".

Answer (score 9):

Seriously, Jisho is so useless; It does not even have 「がし」.

In Classical Japanese, 「がし」 was pronounced and spelt 「かし」 and it was a sentence-ending particle used for ***calling someone's attention, reminding someone of something***, etc. It is, however, no longer used as a sentence-ending particle.

Instead, 「がし」 is used today as a suffix to the **imperative** form of a verb meaning "***as if to say/require/order ~~***".  It carries a bit of a literary flavor (which quite a few people are partial to).  In reality, it is used mostly in a limited number of set phrases such as:

「これ見よがし」= "as if to order you to take a look" ➡ "in a show-offish manner"

「出{で}ていけがしの態度{たいど}」 = "an attiude as if to order you to leave"

Answer (score 1):

They don’t have the word? Anyhow, これ見よがし implies show-off. Such as “iphoneX をこれ見よがしに見せ付ける。” *He ostentatiously shows iphoneX to everyone*

Comment: They had これ見よがし, but it only showed up after searching it exactly as that. Just putting 見よがしturned up nothing, not even stuff relating to that term

Comment: @Roy Fuentes http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97 has some. Anyhow, you can trust l'electuer's exposition.